# Set src depending on url

Tags: javascript

I want to set the souce based on the url

ex:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="test"></script>
```

**i can not add to this

```
 if (window.location.href.indexOf("test") > -1)
  {
     src="myScriptcc.js";
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if ( window.location.href.indexOf ("test") > -1 )
    {
        var myscript = document.createElement ('script');
        myscript.src = 'myScriptcc.js';
        document.body.appendChild (myscript);
    }
</script>
```